# ferronickel temperature coefficient

Tags: resistors, temperature, heat

I'm heating a ferronickel wire, and I need a reliable measurement of temperature, I was using a thermocouple to do this measurement but the wire  is cooled when it's touched by the thermocouple so now I want to estimate the temperature by  the change  of the wire resistance , I'm using the four-wire method to measure so it should be good enough.

Now I need to find 't' from this equation

RT = R20 [ 1 + alfa (t-20)]

I found the [resistivity](https://books.google.co.ve/books?id=Ewaumr4SaG8C&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25&dq=Ferron%C3%ADquel%20(Fe%2BNi)::%090,86&source=bl&ots=FXAin40Hc9&sig=CHnuAZ2NgcUQKaRp4TtD6Pe9Hq0&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwkv-ilrzMAhVJOD4KHUSiCP4Q6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=Ferron%C3%ADquel%20(Fe%2BNi)%3A%3A%090%2C86&f=false)  of the ferronickel to be:

0.86 ohm  mm2/m at ºC

Which is quite accurate, but I can't find alfa

Comment: Can you calibrate it? For example, by placing a sample in a hot oil bath with a co-located thermocouple or RTD.

Comment: can you link and example of that?
Although I will really prefer to find the value of alfa.

Comment: No, I can't. It's an experimental determination of the value of \$\alpha\$. Measure the resistance at two widely separated temperatures and calculate.

Comment: It may not be linear.  Many metals do not have a constant alfa.  There's a full table of Fe-Ni -- unspecified alloy -- at http://www.thermometricscorp.com/PDFs/604-ohm-nickel-iron-rtd-0.00518-in-C.PDF  that specifies a  0.00518 coefficient

Comment: "Balco" may prove a useful search term -- http://precisionsensors.meas-spec.com/pdfs/rtd.pdf specifies 0.518 to 0.527 % per degree C, which matches the previous comment

Answer (score 2):

[Balco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balco_alloy) is 70% Ni and 30% Fe.  The alloy has a temperature coefficient of resistance of 0.00518, with better linearity than pure Ni.  I don't know what your alloy is, but consider that a starting point.